# Including android.support.v7.app dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I'm migrating from Eclipse over to Android Studio and am looking at the Navigation Drawer example from Google. Right away, I see that I get this warning;

[image]

It looks like I need to use the v7 library rather than the v4. I can't figure out how to do this. In Eclipse, I just added a dependency from the build tools, but I see no such option in Android Studio. If I look at the `build.gradle` file, I can see this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

I just downloaded Android Studio yesterday, so I think that I should have this dependency somewhere, but I just don't know how to include it. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Note that switching from an `Activity` with a Navigation Drawer to a full `AppCompat` implementation using an `ActionBarActivity` is potentially a lot of work as per the [announcement post of the latest verison](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). Just because the v4 `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated doesn't mean you are required to switch over everything as part of your move to Android Studio - you can certainly do it as two steps.

Comment: I agree. Looks like the constructor is a bit different and now requires a Toolbar. I might put this off for another day. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within Android Studio, you can go to `File`, `Project Structure`, select your module, and go to the `Dependencies` tab - you'll see a list of dependencies - you can add new dependencies via the `+` sign near the bottom of that screen - it will automatically suggest the most popular libraries and all Google libraries including the one you want: `appcompat-v7`. This controls the `build.gradle` file and, in your case, adds the line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Note that you can also use sites such as [Gradle, please](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/) to manually figure out what the dependency should be and add it to your `build.gradle` file yourself if you'd like.